# Automatic Audio Watermarking of many files

Tags: objective-c, audio, watermark, copy-protection

I have many audio files that I want to protect by watermarking them.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? This can be with a separate software or in objective-c or other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed watermarks to original audio file using **iMovie** application. You can edit the original audio by inserting these low frequency watermarks at required interval and create the desired audio file.